# Terminal borked after invoking Vim with xargs

Tags: terminal, invocation, unix, quit

I've sometimes tried invoking Vim using `xargs`, like this:

```
find . -name '*.java' | xargs vim
```

… which kind of works:

1. As Vim launches, I see the following warning flash briefly:

   > ```
   > Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
   > ```
2. Editing works — `:files` correctly enumerates all of the `.java` files as expected.
3. I can save and quit.

However, after exiting Vim, my terminal is borked:

- Whatever I type at the shell prompt is not echoed.
- Carriage returns don't appear at all, and line feeds only sometimes appear.

This goes on until I issue a [`reset(1)`](http://man.cx/tset(1)) command to reinitialize the terminal.

Is this a Vim bug, or is there a more satisfactory explanation for why it interacts with the terminal like that?  I've seen it happen on Vim up to version 7.3 (the version doesn't seem to matter) on Linux and various Unices.

I'm aware of one workaround, namely `vim $(find . -name '*.java')`.  Other workarounds would be welcome, though that's not my main question.

Comment: I kind of get your desire to fill up this site with as many questions as possible but… that question has been answered dozens of times over the years on SO/SU and elsewhere: `xargs` uses a dummy `stdin` that can't be used by Vim and breaks everything afterwards.

Comment: @romainl I'm not active on those sites, and I've never seen it asked there — honest.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/336016/invoking-vi-through-find-xargs-breaks-my-terminal-why - perhaps someone can condense the top answers to a great answer.

Comment: Great question - this has happened to me numerous times. Also, I don't use any other SO sites - if it's vim-related, I'd like to find it here.

Answer (score 32):

This happens when vim is invoked and it's connected to the previous pipeline's output, instead of the terminal and it's receiving different unexpected input (like NULs).
The same happens when you run: `vim < /dev/null`, so `reset` command in this case helps. This is explained well by [grawity at superuser](https://superuser.com/a/336020/87805).

If you're using `find` to pass file names to edit, you don't need `xargs`, just use `-exec`, in example:

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec vim {} +
```

---

If you'd like to use `xargs`, on Unix/macOS you should use `-o` parameter, like:

```
find . -name '*.java' | xargs -o vim
```

> <sup>`-o` Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process before executing the command.  This is useful if you want xargs to run an interactive application.</sup>

or:

```
find . -name "*.java" -type f -print0 | xargs -o -0 vim
```

<sup>Note: Using `-print0`/`-0` will support filenames with whitespaces.</sup>

---

#### `find` + [BSD `xargs`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/1/xargs/)

On Unix/macOS you can try the following workaround:

```
find . -name '*.java' | xargs -J% sh -c 'vim < /dev/tty $@'
```

---

You can also use [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) syntax, for example:

```
vim $(find . -name '*.java')
vim `find . -name '*.java`
```

Alternatively use GNU `parallel` instead of `xargs` to force tty allocation, in example:

```
find . -name '*.java' | parallel -X --tty vi
```

<sup>Note: `parallel`on Unix/OSX won't work as it has different parameters and it doesn't support tty.</sup>

<sup>Many other popular commands provides pseudo-tty allocation as well (like `-t` in `ssh`), so check for help.</sup>

Other suggestion would be to use:

- [`ex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor)) command-line editor to parse the data or use Ex mode, for more details see:

  [How to edit files non-interactively (e.g. in pipeline)?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/467)
- [`vipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/vipe) (a Vim command pipe)
- use the following simple script:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  # usage: find ... | vip
  exec vim < /dev/tty "$@"
  ```

Related:

- [Bug GH-982: vim does not handle STDIN set to /dev/null](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/982).
- [Invoking vi through find | xargs breaks my terminal. Why?](https://superuser.com/questions/336016/invoking-vi-through-find-xargs-breaks-my-terminal-why) at superuser SE
- [Vim exec command in command line, and Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517568/vim-exec-command-in-command-line-and-vim-warning-input-is-not-from-a-terminal) at stackoverflow
- [Trying to “locate” and then open a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45782/trying-to-locate-and-then-open-a-file) at unix SE
- [less.vim not working on my Ubuntu 12.04 lts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443205/less-vim-not-working-on-my-ubuntu-12-04-lts) at askubuntu SE
- [`grep -l .. | xargs vim` generates a warning, why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77395/grep-l-xargs-vim-generates-a-warning-why) [dup] at unix SE
- [Vim Input is not from a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281304/vim-input-is-not-from-a-terminal) [dup] at stackoverflow SE
- BashFAQ/021: [How can I replace a string with another string in a variable, a stream, a file, or in all the files in a directory?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021)

Comment: My GNU `xargs` doesn't have `-J`. That seems to be a MacOS  (BSD) option that's not present in the GNU version.

Answer (score 13):

#### Workaround suggestion: use a buffer as a filesystem navigator

Use the `vim -` command to read a list of paths from stdin. Vim's [`:help --`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#--) explains this:<sup>1</sup>

> Start editing a new buffer, which is filled with text that is read
>   from stdin.  The commands that would normally be read from stdin will
>   now be read from stderr.  Example:
>
> ```
> find . -name "*.c" -print | vim -
> ```

You can then use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-f</kbd> to navigate to the file in the same buffer or in a new split window respectively.

#### Workaround suggestion: argument list

Another great way is to use the Vim's argument list. The `:argadd **/*.java` command will populate Vim's argument list with all the java files found inside the current directory recursively. You can then use the `:next` and `:prev` to move between the files.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The first `-` tells Vim you want to search the help for a command line option, the second is actually the command line flag you're searching for. Read [`:help help-context`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/help.txt.html#help-context) for more tricks like this.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

Besides `reset`, you can try:

```
stty sane
```

which should also make your terminal usable again.

See [here](https://superuser.com/a/336020/56124) for explanations. 
And somehow this can be considered a vim misbehavior, at least [Neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim) doesn't have this issue at the moment.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question, but it helped me, so +1.

Comment: This DOES answer my question ;) Though after reading the OP more I guess `reset` should too.

Answer (score 8):

The reason is that `xargs` sets `stdin` to `/dev/null`, whereas `vim` needs `stdin` to be `/dev/tty`.

---

**BSD `xargs` (e.g. Mac) solution:**

```
echo -e 'file1\nfile2' | xargs -o vim
```

`-o` sets the `stdin` of xarg's child process (`vim` in this case) to `dev/tty`.

---

**GNU `xargs` (e.g. Linux) solution:**

GNU `xargs` does not have the `-o` option. Instead you will have to use a more complicated workaround. (Note: It is very important to have the trailing `zero` string, don't forget it.)

```
echo -e 'file1\nfile2' | xargs bash -c '</dev/tty vim "$@"' zero
```

You can also make it an alias:

```
alias vimin='xargs bash -c '\''</dev/tty vim "$@"'\'' zero'
echo -e 'file1\nfile2' | vimin
```

---

**Detailed explanation of GNU xargs solution**

Let's break it down step by step:

```
echo -e 'file1\nfile2' | xargs bash -c '</dev/tty vim "$@"' zero
```

1. `xargs` simply appends the `stdin` to the end of the string, so `xargs` will be executing this:

```
    bash -c '</dev/tty vim "$@"' zero file1 file2
```

2. The format for `bash -c` is `bash -c 'COMMAND_STRING' $0 $1 $2 etc`.

`"$@"` expands to the positional parameters `"$1", "$2"`, etc. It does not include "$0" because that is a special parameter for the script name, not a positional parameter. **This is why we need to add the dummy string `zero` (it can be any string) to take the place for `$0`. Otherwise, you will lose the first file.**

So after you expand `"$@"`, you end up with:

```
    bash -c '</dev/tty vim file1 file2'
```

3. `bash -c` will execute the COMMAND_STRING:

```
    </dev/tty vim file1 file2
```

`</dev/tty` sets the `stdin` to `/dev/tty` so that `vim` can work in interactive mode.

Comment: +1 This would seem to be a duplicate of the answer with the highest number of votes, but it's not. The `$0` placeholder (here "zero") is the key.

Comment: why `bash -c` would be helpful or needed?

Answer (score 0):

I have found all of these answers lacking. After struggling through the xargs issue, the very simplest way--for me!--to do these search-and-opens on a generic box is the following:

```
vim -O `grep -lir mySearchTerm *`
```

I have no issue using `find` with `xargs` and `grep`, but I find the syntax annoying. And as a daily coder who uses `vim` and the terminal as their IDE, and searches files for properties constantly, this is what I have been using.

There is a time and place for `find . -path ./node_modules -prune -o -name '*.js' | xargs grep -i mySearchTerm` coupled with opening files via vim, and other methods. For me, that is rarely.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: FWIW it is recommended not to use the legacy backticks notation and to use `$(...)` instead. It is not as important in your command line as in a script but I think it's still better to use that in your answers :) (references [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) and [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03))