# neovim does not work after a "| xargs"

Tags: neovim

If I issue the following command:

`ls  sb.ovpn | xargs  vim`

The classic vim opens the sb.ovpn file.

However if I do the same but with neovim:

`ls  sb.ovpn | xargs nvim -`

That does not work as I expected, opens a new file instead (without dash does not work either). ¿Why? ¿Is that the expected behavior of nvim?

Comment: `xargs vim` isn't known to work all that well either: https://superuser.com/q/336016/334516, https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/410/terminal-borked-after-invoking-vim-with-xargs, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77395/grep-l-xargs-vim-generates-a-warning-why

Comment: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/8561

Answer (score 2):

This is a (side?)effect of the changes from nvim v0.2.2 -> v0.3.  Nvim did switch the default behaviour for text that is piped into it via stdin.  Before it was used as commands (unless `-` was given as an argument), now it is used as text in the initial buffer (even without the `-`).

Your file argument should be there just as the next buffer in the *internal* argument list of neovim.  Try `:ls` inside neovim.

You can verify that this behaviour is new with neovim v0.3 when you download the [appimage for v0.2.2](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/tag/v0.2.2) and try the same with that.

**EDIT**: I confirmed that for version 0.3.1 it works as expected, you get file in the first buffer.  You can download v0.3.1 from [the release page](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/tag/v0.3.1). (thanks @jamessan for mentioning)

Comment: There was no 0.2.3 release. :) 0.3.1 has the fix.

Comment: @jamessan I have a nvim.appimage which reports `v0.2.3-1-gd6f9d1df0` for `--version`. I don't remember where I got it.

Comment: That's a nightly build, not an official release.  Initially, the release after 0.2.2 was going to be 0.2.3, but then it was decided to change to 0.3.0.